# make a unique enumeration for concatenated pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have some dataframes where data is tagged in groups, let's say as such:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,3,7, 10,30, 70, 100, 300], 'name':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 'tag': [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[2,5,6, 20, 50, 200, 500, 600], 'name': [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'tag':[1,1,1, 2, 2, 3,3,3]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[4, 8, 9, 40, 400, 800, 900], 'name': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 'tag':[1,1,1, 2, 3, 3,3]})
```

In each dataframe, the tag is attibuted in an ascending order of ids (so bigger ids will have equal or bigger tags).
My wish is to recalculate tags in the concatenated dataframe,

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

so that the tag of each group will be in ascending order of ids of the first element of each. So, the group starting by id=1 will be tagged by 1 (that is, ids 1,3,7), the group starting by id=2 will be tagged by 2 (that is , ids 2,5,6), the group starting by 4 will be tagged by 3, the group starting by 10 will be tagged as 4, and so on.

I did manage to get a (complicated!) solution:

1) Get first row of each group , put those in a dataframe , sort by id and create the new tags:

```
dff = pd.concat([df1.groupby('tag').first(), df2.groupby('tag').first(), df3.groupby('tag').first()])
dff = dff.sort(['id'])
dff = dff.reset_index()
dff['new_tags'] = dff.index +1
```

2) Concatenate this dataframe with initial ones, drop_duplicates so as to keep the newly tagged rows, order by group , then propagate new tags:

```
df = pd.concat([dff, df1, df2, df3])
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'tag', 'name'])
df = df.sort(['name', 'tag'])
df = df.fillna(method = 'pad')
```

The new tags are exactly what needed, but my solution seems too complicated. Would you have a suggestion on how to make easier? I think I must be missing something!

Thanks in advance,

M.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.concat` + `keys` , I break down the steps

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],keys=[0,1,2])
df=df.reset_index(level=0)#get the level=0 index 
df=df.sort_values(['tag','level_0']) # sort the value 

df['New']=(df['tag'].diff().ne(0)|df['level_0'].diff().ne(0)).cumsum()
df
Out[110]: 
   level_0   id  name  tag  New
0        0    1     1    1    1
1        0    3     1    1    1
2        0    7     1    1    1
0        1    2     2    1    2
1        1    5     2    1    2
2        1    6     2    1    2
0        2    4     3    1    3
1        2    8     3    1    3
2        2    9     3    1    3
3        0   10     1    2    4
4        0   30     1    2    4
5        0   70     1    2    4
3        1   20     2    2    5
4        1   50     2    2    5
3        2   40     3    2    6
6        0  100     1    3    7
7        0  300     1    3    7
5        1  200     2    3    8
6        1  500     2    3    8
7        1  600     2    3    8
4        2  400     3    3    9
5        2  800     3    3    9
6        2  900     3    3    9
```

Comment: although it works for the example given because of the order of concatenation is related to the order of the first value in each tag, it  won't give the expected output if you change let's say in `df1`: id =1 becomes 2 and in `df2`: id=2 becomes 1. because at any moment in this method, you sort by `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Once concatenated, you can use `groupby` the columns 'tag' and 'name' with `transform` and `first` on the column 'id'. Then `sort_values` this series and `cumsum` the `diff` is more than 0 such as:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)
df['new'] = (df.groupby(['tag','name'])['id'].transform('first')
               .sort_values().diff().ne(0.).cumsum())
```

and you get the expected output:

```
     id  name  tag  new
0     1     1    1    1
1     2     2    1    2
2     3     1    1    1
3     4     3    1    3
4     5     2    1    2
5     6     2    1    2
6     7     1    1    1
7     8     3    1    3
8     9     3    1    3
9    10     1    2    4
10   20     2    2    5
11   30     1    2    4
12   40     3    2    6
...
```

EDIT: to avoid using `groupby`, you can `drop_duplicates` and `index` to get the index of the first ids, create the column new with an incremental value using `loc` and `range` and then `ffill` after `sort_values` to fill the values:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)
list_ind = df.drop_duplicates(['name','tag']).index
df.loc[list_ind,'new'] = range(1,len(list_ind)+1)
df['new'] = df.sort_values(['tag','name'])['new'].ffill().astype(int)
```

and you get the same result